# Biological Neural Network Modification to Unlearn Understandings

Tags: neuroscience, brain, neurophysiology

Lets assume that a person grows up thinking that religion X is true religion. So he builds up a profile in ones head and when notion of religion X appears the neurons that is related are fired, giving sensation of God and related stuff.

Lets us also assume that later in life he learns that religion X was not correct, then does "realization" of this fact happens by modifying old neural networks or a new profile is created for religion X and old profile gets deleted?

In other words do neurons associated with sensation that religion X was true religion "modified" or a new network is created giving a new sensation that religion X was not true religion along!

In my general understanding modification of old network could be challenging assuming that they are surrounded by other neurons associated with other stuff, a certain modification by having more or less neurons would result in borrowing neighboring neurons and wiring them to create a modification or loosing some connections to create a modification, which doesn't seem efficient.

---

I am not sure how is this question "opinion based"? I have asked a concrete question with a general example.

Comment: i'd suggest putting this on psychology and neuroscience instead, I don't know if you're going to get a good answer here: https://psychology.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I will, do you think its not related to biology?

Comment: Why was this close as opinion-based?

Comment: @BiologyEnthusiast Since there is a SE site specifically pointed towards neuroscience and cognition, that is likely a much better place to get informed commentary. Moreover, I personally can't tell if there is enough information to answer the question but I suspect there might not be (for example, there are no linked sources); this suggests to me that an expert would need to look at it to decide whether it can be answered. That expert would be a psychologist or a neuroscientist; and such specialists have their own site.

Comment: This has now been cross-posted at Psych&Neuro. I don't necessarily agree that it should have been closed here, but I think now that it's been posted there it shouldn't be reopened here.